# Append multiple divs to new location (using .prev)

Tags: jquery, function, append, each

Basically i need to move all the links in a selection of divs inside the div.item

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="inner">
    <a class="link">HELLO</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="inner">
    <a class="link">HELLO</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

ive been playing ab out with the following script but just cant seem to nail it

```
  $( ".link" ).each(function(){
    var prevbox = $(this).prev('.item');
    $(this).appendTo(prevbox);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".link").each(function() {
  var prevbox = $(this).closest('.item');
  $(this).appendTo(prevbox);
});

console.log($('.item')[0].outerHTML)
```

```css
.inner {
  background-color: green
}
.link {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="inner">w
    <a class="link">HELLO</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="inner">e
    <a class="link">HELLO</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You want to get the `.closest('.item')`

Answer (score 0):

The `.each` function is unnecessary because it'll automatically perform it on every instance of the element.

Calling `.prev` is also unnecessary unless you're trying to do a conditional thing for only the elements that contain a `.link`.

I believe this is all you want:

```
$(".item").append("<div class='link'>asdf</div>");
```